# Passing values from ansible code to airflow DAG using xcom

Tags: bash, ansible, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Using BashOperator to trigger ansible playbook from airflow DAG task, in that I want to fetch the value which are generated in Task 1 and use those in airflow DAG Task 2.

Task 1 executes a ansible playbook in which this value is generated. Is there a way to get that value in airflow DAG Task 2. Following below doc, but couldn't find any sample code which covers ansible playbook use-case.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/operators/bash.py#L40

Comment: Can you make a python function `trigger_ansible` and add `output_ansible=subprocess.run(f"command_to_trigger_ansible", shell=True, capture_output=True).output` and  then push `output_ansible` to xcoms?

Answer (score 0):

The BashOperator pushes its result to an XCOM by default.

There is a caveat though. Only the last line of your bash command is stored in the XCOM.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

with DAG('ansible_dag_poc', start_date=days_ago(1), schedule_interval='@daily', catchup=False) as dag:

    ping_nodes = BashOperator(task_id="ping_nodes", bash_command='ansible all -m ping')

    @task
    def print_nodes_status(return_value):
        print('print node status', return_value)

    ls_files >> print_nodes_status(return_value=ping_nodes.output)
```

For your usecase, you need to implement a custom operator that returns all the lines from running your ansible command.

Then parse the output in your next task to get the value.

```py
import subprocess
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

with DAG('ansible_poc_2', start_date=days_ago(1), schedule_interval='@daily', catchup=False) as dag:

    @task
    def ping_nodes():
        result = subprocess.run('ansible all -m ping'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        return result.stdout.decode('utf-8')

    @task
    def print_nodes_status(return_value):
        # Parse value in return_value
        print('print return value', return_value)

   
    print_nodes_status(ping_nodes())
```